# Parse app not working on real device "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1" Swift 2.0 Xcode 7 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I have downloaded the parse core quick start swift Xcode project.  It runs perfectly fine in the simulator: I can create users, upload data, etc...  But when I try to run it on my physical device I get this error in Xcode: `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`  I am sure that I have all the needed library's because the project is strait from parse.com.  FWI I'm on Swift 2 Xcode 7 beta 6.  I don't think that it's an error in the code but here is my app delegate:

```
import UIKit
import Bolts
import Parse

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
        Parse.setApplicationId("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            clientKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

        let defaultACL = PFACL();
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)
        PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

        return true
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
        installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
        installation.saveInBackground()

        PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            if succeeded {
                print("good");
            } else {
                print("bad", error)
            }
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
        if error.code == 3010 {
            print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
        } else {
            print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
        }
    }

    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }
}
```

And my ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let testObject = PFObject(className: "TestObject")
        testObject["foo"] = "bar"
        testObject.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            print("Object has been saved.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if deleting your derived data folder fixes it.

Also, you may want to change your Parse keys, since you just posted them on StackOverflow.

Comment: Deleting everything in derived data folder did not fix it.  Any other ideas?Parse keys removed and changed.